# how to set cell of height according to image Size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm getting image from URL in different different sizes. I have set cell hight on the basis of image height.

```
[cell.imgshow setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImageUrl]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"preloader_img_1.png"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    cell.imgshow.image = image;
    imageStatus =@"Load";

    if (image != nil) {
        // [images insertObject:image atIndex:indexPath.row];
        [images setObject:image forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li,%li",(long)indexPath.row,(long)indexPath.section]];
        NSLog(@"%@",images);
        [tblDropDown reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
```

That's code I'm using for image load and refersh code.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIImage *image = (UIImage *)[images objectForKey:
                                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li,%li",
                                  (long)indexPath.row,(long)indexPath.section]];

    if (image != nil)
    {
        return image.size.height+300;
    }
    else{
        return 300.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have u tried to do the following by auto layout rather than doing it by code?

Comment: What's your question or issue? You posted some code but didn't say what the issue is.

Comment: i have to set cell height according to image size.

Comment: The code you posted should do that so what is issue that you have with the code?

Comment: I m not able to set cell height according to image size

Answer (score 1):

Hope That may help you.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ...

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                    success:^(UIImage *image, BOOL cached) {

                        // save height of an image to some cache
                        [self.heightsCache setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:imHeight] 
                                              forKey:urlKey];

                        [tableView beginUpdates];
                        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                        [tableView endUpdates];
                    }
                    failure:^(NSError *error) {... failure code here ...}];

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // try to get image height from your own heights cache
    // if its is not there return default one
    CGFloat height = [[self.heightsCache objectForKey:urlKeyFromModelsArrayForThisCell] floatValue];
    ...
    return newHeight;
}
```

For More information refer the following link.

https://github.com/jurezove/dynamic-uitableviewcells/tree/master

Comment: Don't just post code with no explanation. What was wrong? How does your answer solve the issue?

Comment: @rmaddy i din't post the answer to satisfy your need.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataSource` method heightForRowAtIndexPath is executed before `cellForRowAtIndexPath` while populating `UITableView`, so first you have to return a proper height for the cell from `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, you can't set the height of UITableViewCell from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.